# What about biochemistry in Stephen King's Autopsy Room Four?

Tags: short-stories, stephen-king, biology

I have just listened to (the Polish version, if that matters) of "Autopsy Room Four" by Stephen King. Either I am missing some part or something obvious or the whole story is simply impossible.

**How could the main character be conscious and alive so long without oxygen in his brain?**

1. King didn't explain (or I missed this when listening) whether the main character's heart was or wasn't beating, but we can assume that it was not beating, because otherwise the whole story doesn't make sense, because no one reasonable would start an autopsy on a "corpse" with a beating heart.
2. If the main character's heart was not beating then what about biochemistry? How could he remain conscious for the period of the whole story (approximately 30 minutes?) if after 5-10 minutes at most his brain would be dead without oxygen?

I do recall King (main character) himself saying in this story that the brain remains conscious for only three minutes after the heart stops while in this story it seems that the main character's brain remained "working" for at least half an hour without oxygen.

Can anyone help me understand what am I missing in this story? Can someone cite here the parts of the story that I missed / misunderstood and that lead me to having the above doubts?

Unfortunately, I am unable to listen or read it again and that's why I had to ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after answering it, it's not sci-fi, and is asking for a scientific explanation. Maybe Literature SE?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It can be classified as horror and it's about details of story, not if it's actually possible, so I wouldn't say it's off-topic.

Comment: Horror is not always sci-fi as we've covered it so far, but I'll yield the second one. :)

Comment: From what I was told and learnt during my 40+ years old, it is simply impossible to not detect a person still has a vitals when preparing for an autopsy. I still don't believe this is possible, despite the answer below. Having this in mind, I assume that this guy's heart was off and surviving conscious for 30+ without oxygen in brain made this a purely SF story as per me and that's why I did ask here. Having assumption corrected, making this guy actually living, makes this story a full feature horror and this question -- off-topic. Thanks and sorry for false shot.

Comment: No worries. It happens all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, they never checked his vitals, so it is implied that his heart, and breathing, are operating, if maybe so slowly that they can't tell by a visual inspection. Part of his internal monologue in the short story notes this.

> .... Of course I had bad luck — I know Dr. Jennings, remember speaking to him as I played through his foursome on the eleventh hole. A nice enough guy, but vague, an antique. The antique had pronounced me dead. Then *Rusty*, with his dopey green eyes and his detention-hall grin, had pronounced me dead. The lady doc, Ms. Cico Kid, hadn't even *looked* at me yet, not really. When she did, maybe—

What is implied to have happened is that the snakebite paralyzed him completely, even his heart, long enough for Dr. Jennings to pronounce him dead on site, and then no one thought to check because he looked dead, including a lack of pupilary response. However, the fact that he's still able to smell things, and that he was able to eventually start making noise through his nose means he must be breathing, if very shallowly.